# Looking for better way to construct string in Text composition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Jetpack Compose and made a flash card app for my kid. Everything works and now I'm trying to refactor it to follow best practices. It's stated that you shouldn't use hard coded text and to place your strings in the res/values/strings.xml file. I've done that for all my strings but this one seems messy and overly complicated. Is there a better way to do this?

```kotlin
text = "You scored $answersCorrect out of 10 in $totalTime seconds" //Original String

text = "${stringResource(R.string.You_scored)} $answersCorrect ${stringResource(
            R.string.Out_of)} $totalTime ${stringResource(R.string.Seconds)}"

<string name="You_scored">You scored </string>
<string name="Out_of"> out of 10 in</string>
<string name="Seconds"> seconds</string>
```

They both work but I feel there is a better way to implement the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to split your text into 3 string resources, just define the parameters you want to pass in the string res and pass it when getting the resource

in XML

```
 <string name="your_string_id">You scored %1$d out of 10 in %2$d seconds</string>
```

in compose

```
stringResource(R.string.your_string_id, answersCorrect, totalTime)
```

the above example assumes answersCorrect and totalTime is a numeric value, if you want to pass a string use %1$s, %2$s instead